# Hide subdivision dots/normals in edit mode?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, normals

Somehow I managed to activate a display where I see a lot of dots (normals?) when I'm in edit mode and the object is subdivided.

The image to the left is without the subsurf, and the right is with it on, but I still want to "Display modifier in viewport".

This only happens in Face select mode, but I don't remember it looking like this...?

It doesn't happen when I create a new object, so it seems to be an object setting. I think I have pressed a shortcut but mistake somehow...

[image]

Comment: never seen something like that... I guess you set multiple subdivs? can you share at least that portion of the file (eg: through http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and/or show some more mesh/subdiv setting?

Comment: Thanks, while I tried to simplify my blend-file to post it, i discovered that it was fixed when I deleted the armature, which led me to the answer below.

Comment: Ah, ok. I got the same effect setting two subdivs, and the same "cage" option on the second one... good.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, I had "Adjust edit cage to modifier result" on the rig I was working on:

[image]